# Django NoReverseMatch Registration App

Tags: django, web

I installed the Django app called registration. I set up templates, added to the url and view files and everything worked just dandy. Now I have an issues re logging into the system after i logout(which never happened before) I clear the cookies and browsing history from my browser (I tried multiple ones to see if that was the problem) and got to "/registration/login/" and I type the information and I can login. I click my logout button and it logs me out everything is in order. The problem is when i go to log in a second time i go to "/registration/login/" and type my information into the form and submit and get

```
NoReverseMatch at /registration/login/
Reverse for '' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://genie:8181/registration/login/
Django Version: 1.5.2
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    
Reverse for '' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.
Exception Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py     in _reverse_with_prefix, line 416
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.3
Python Path:    
['/var/www/RegCal',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/South-0.8.2-py2.7.egg',
'/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/distribute-0.7.3-py2.7.egg',
'/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools-1.1.6-py2.7.egg',
'/usr/lib/python2.7',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
'/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages']
Server time:    Tue, 8 Oct 2013 17:18:11 -0500
Traceback Switch to copy-and-paste view

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py in get_response
                    response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) ...
 ▶ Local vars
 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/views/decorators/debug.py in      sensitive_post_parameters_wrapper
          return view(request, *args, **kwargs) ...
```

Now usually these errors will give a name in the "Reverse for '' with" along with a line number and its usually a URL problem. What I do'nt understand is if I can access this URL why won't the form post to it. Thanks in advance for any tips or hints let me know what you need to see and I will upload it.

Template file for login 
    {% extends 'base.html' %}

```
{% block title %} | Please login{% endblock title %}

{% block content %}
    {% if forms.errors %}
        <p>Sorry, that's not a valid username or password</p>
    {% endif %}
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <form id="login_small" class="span6" action="{{ app_path }}" method="post" >{% csrf_token %}
            <div class="span4 pic"></div>

            <div class="span8">
                <span></span>
                <input type="text" name="username" value="Username" id="username">
                <input type="password" name="password" value="password" id="password">
                <input type="submit" value="login" class="submit_but" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>

{% endblock content %}
```

Just a note that I have tried changing {{ app_path }} but it didn't change anything I still got the same error

URL Patterns File:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    #Get urls from the userprofile app
    url(r'^account/', include('userprofile.urls')),

    #URL Patterns for the registration apps
    url(r'^registration/', include('registration.backends.default.urls')),

    #Site Admin URL Patterns
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

    #Day URL Patterns
    url(r'^view/day/(\d+)/(\d+)/(\d+)/$', 'courseCalendar.views.day'),
    url(r'^view/day$', 'courseCalendar.views.day'),

    #Month URL Patterns
    url(r'^view/month$', 'courseCalendar.views.month'),
    url(r'^view/month/(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<month>\d{1,2})$', 'courseCalendar.views.month'),
    url(r'^view/month/(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<month>\d{1,2})/(?P<change>\w+)$', 'courseCalendar.views.month'),

    #Year URL Patterns
    url(r"^view/year/(?P<year>\d+)$", 'courseCalendar.views.year'),

    #Course Edit Patterns
    url(r"^edit/course/(?P<courseID>\d+)$", 'courseCalendar.views.courseEdit'),
    url(r"^edit/course$", 'courseCalendar.views.courseEdit'),

    #Enroll Student Page
    url(r"^enroll/(?P<courseID>\d+)/(?P<userID>\d+)$", 'courseCalendar.views.enroll'),

    #Search through existing courses
    url(r"^search/$", 'courseCalendar.views.courseSearch'),

    #Root Directory Pattern
    url(r'', 'courseCalendar.views.year'),
)
```

Comment: Well it seems it is trying to reverse an empty sequence hence `''`, post your template

Comment: I tried changing it from app_path to  "/registration/login/" but it didn't change

Comment: could you add your urls.py?

Comment: I never used to have the problem and I can access the URL regularly by typing it in but when the form posts I get this Error with no arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I feel really goofy for this. The reason I was getting this error is because I had LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = ''. I figured that was the issue by entering different arguments into the next parameter of the URL which allowed me to log in. At first I thought it was my url file not catching the request for a root directory but that didn't make sense because I could hit the root url and be served a page. I decided to look through the settings page and I came across that line changed it and we were back to normal.